# Is it possible to change signalr/hubs script?

Tags: signalr

I use signalr on site where there is already another jQuery version. I needed to change jQuery alias. Is it possible to modify script that is returned from ~/signalr/hubs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, write a custom [`IJavaScriptProxyGenerator`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/IJavaScriptProxyGenerator.cs) and plug it into the `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver` at startup and SignalR will generate the scripts using that instead.

In your case I would start by copying the [the `DefaultJavaScriptProxyGenerator` implementation](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/DefaultJavaScriptProxyGenerator.cs) and the template `/SignalR/Scripts/hubs.js` file and then replace the aliases used in those two places with whatever makes sense for you.